# javascript iterate over string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a **string** like this:

```
Cars: 5
Fruits: 2
Cars: 1
Carrier: 20
Cars: 20
Hey: 2"
```

How do I get all the Cars values into an Array?

I want to end up with this:

```
[5, 1, 20]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably go with something like this, based on John Resig's "Search and don't replace" method.:

```
var arr = [];
str.replace(/Cars:\s(\d+)/g, function ($0, num) {
    arr.push(+num);
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wCLTe/1**

Comment: Oh did not realize you can use a function as the second argument. Nice, i was thinking about using match or something crazy like that. \d+ though

Comment: @Mark: yeah, whoops I missed that `+`.